# Attending conference in Norway with my spouse

Tags: visas, schengen, norway, bangladeshi-citizens

I am going to attend an academic conference in Norway in upcoming June. I am a PhD student in the USA and hold an F1 visa. I want to take my wife with me to Norway. She holds an F2 visa here. I understand the correct visa for me is a business visa. What would be an appropriate type of visa for her? And do we need to apply separately for visa or there is a joint type visa?

To clarify we both are from Bangladesh. So we both need a Schengen visa.

Comment: Should we assume that your wife is a citizen of a country whose citizens need visas to enter the Schengen area?  If she is, for example, Mexican, then she does not need a visa at all.

Comment: You appear to have created two accounts, [S M Ferdous](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75119/s-m-ferdous) and [Ferdous](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/75120/ferdous).  You can [merge](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the conference is longer than 90 days, you both need a Schengen short-stay visa, which is also known as a Type C visa.  The Schengen area does not subdivide the type C visa into different classes, but the [application form](http://www.vfsglobal.com/norway/usa/pdf/Schengen_Visa_Application_Form_150907.pdf) does ask you to specify the main purpose of your visit using one of several choices:

- Tourism
- Business
- Visiting family or friends
- Cultural
- Sports
- Official visit
- Medical reasons
- Study
- Transit
- Airport transit
- Other (please specify)

Your wife could either choose "tourism" or "other"; in the latter case she would add something along the lines of "accompany S M Ferdous to conference."

You and your wife will need to submit separate applications, but you should each refer to the other's application in your cover letter.  The cover letter is required; you can see the list of other required documents by visiting the [visitor's visa page for applicants in the US](https://www.norway.no/en/usa/services-info/visitors-visa-res-permit/visitors-visa/#necessary-doc) and following the "Document Checklist" link in the second section of the page.